# React Router v4 with Express not rendering outside entry jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on adding pages to my existing app, things are running fine for the home page but any no other pages will render and I get what looks like an Express "cannot GET /page1" error.

My Express server is running at the same time and I use webpack to proxy the api like so:

```
devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      '^/api/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is a sample of how the rest of my app is set up:

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Home from './pages/Home.jsx';
import Page1 from './pages/Page1.jsx';

render((
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  ),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <h1>Home</h1>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**Page1.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class Page1 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Page1</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page1;
```

**Express App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var users = require('./routes/users');
var config = require('./config.js');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/users', users);

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Are you navigating directly to the URL using your browser?

Comment: You need to make sure Express is serving up the same location regardless of the url. Express is trying to resolve /page1 and it's never making it to React-Router, so something like app.use('*',(res,req) =>{ //always return devServer});

Comment: @Budhead2004 this was basically what was happening, but instead of always returning the devServer I needed to return the index.html file that react renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with a similar approach that @Budhead2004 was offering. In case anyone else comes across here - this is what I changed to get it to work. I had to basically serve up the react entry point (index.html) that the app renders to, on all routes with Express, like so in my app.js file:

```
app.use('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a couple things

1. You have webpack dev server & express on the same port which leads me to believe that
2. You are not running the webpack dev server at all.

Express isn't going to serve your webpack stuff, webpack will serve your webpack stuff. Try changing `devServer.port` to anything other than `3000`, run webpack, and debug from there.

[Here are the webpack dev server docs to get you started](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

Also as a side note, you don't need to import `render` in your React component, extending from Component will handle it.

Comment: I'm running `webpack -d --watch` alongside with the server, is this what you're referring to as running the dev server?